# Forming a new layer that is the common area between two other layers on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

My aim is to find the above-ground biomass of Mangrove forests in specific districts. I was able to map the layers on each other and find the average biomass of the total area but was not able to isolate it to only the mangrove forests.

```js
var districts = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2");
var mang_2020 = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-ak7221/assets/2020");
var district = districts.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Cidade da Beira'));
var mang_district = mang_2020.filterBounds(district.geometry())
var styleParams = {
  color: '00909F',
  width: 1.0,
};
//The Biomass dataset and clipping it
var l4b = ee.Image('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI04_B_002').select('MU')
var clipped = l4b.clip(district)
var area = clipped;
Map.addLayer(clipped,{min: 10, max: 250, palette: '440154,414387,2a788e,23a884,7ad151,fde725'},'Mean Biomass');
Map.addLayer(mang_district, {color: 'blue'}, '2020-2022');

print(l4b.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),geometry: district,}).get('MU'));
```

and the dataset is here: [Dataset_Biomass](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LARSE_GEDI_GEDI04_B_002),[Dataset_Mangrove](https://wcmc.io/GMW_2020)

PS: The mangrove dataset is an external document. if you want to avoid uploading it, you could replace it with any other featureCollection to form a new layer it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to solve the issue by changing the geometry l4b.reduceRegion to

```
print(l4b.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),geometry: mang_district,}).get('MU'));
```

small change but it helped